# First machine with dedicated scatter/gather?

Tags: history, cray

I know the Cray-1 had scatter/gather addressing, but I am curious if anyone knows what the first machine with this feature might be?

I suspect it is one of the vector machines from this era, perhaps STAR-100 or the Goodyear systems. But perhaps it was one of IBM's late 60's supers?

Comment: [This](http://gordonbell.azurewebsites.net/digital/pdp11_arch_enhance_strategy_75.pdf) Digital Interoffice Memorandum (dated February 13 1975) discusses scatter/gather mapped I/O for the PDP-11 family and what features the competition already supports.

Comment: AFAIR the gather/scatter addressing of a Cray was more of an indexed load, i.e. a vector had to be loaded with the indices and then used to load the vector to operate on (each limited to 64 entries). It also had to hold that loading vector (or reload it) for scattering.  A process resulting from and restricted to vector designs. Without that restriction, I'd say any machine providing indexed addressing will provide scatter/gather, and qualify here wouldn't it? If restricted to only vector machines, then Cray-1 is the answer, as the STAR worked on memory.

Comment: Thinking of it, strictly any machine using interleaved memory is also prepared for gather/scatter operation. 32 way interleave is what made the STAR fast in the first place (it's core memory wouldn't had otherwise the speed to feed any kind of vector operation past a few hundred kilopops (memory access cycle in 1970 lingered around 3 µs for core) . Now, if interleaved works for the question (read having the vector adapted to memory interleave scheme - which STAR and CRAY-1 did) than the first machine with more than one memory bank, that could operate interleaved, will answer.

Comment: Taking this at whole, It seems the question makes only sense for a very specific context of vector processors, as it does not exist for computers in general, only in context of programming algorithms. (Additional fact about STAR vs. CRAY,  the STAR's structure for solving sparse arrays was, AFAIR, not gather/scatter but mask orientated, kinda like in APL).

Comment: @Raffzahn What does scatter/gather mean to you?  I know of it in the context of DMA I/O; where it means (to my understanding) to allow a single I/O transfer to read or write to multiple areas of memory.  But your comments seem to be about a different meaning for scatter/gather.

Comment: @Raffzahn Never mind, I found it.  It is indeed a term of art with multiple meanings.  I should have known!

Comment: @WayneConrad Well, it does of course have at first the meaning of continuous IO from/to different memory areas to me. One of the very basic items that made the /360 very good at reaching high I/O thruput. Like collecting various actions for a drive/controller, sorting them and having them acted in one transaction - stuff modern systems rediscover :)) But I believe the context of this question is about operating on an indexed vector of (float) items like used in super computers (and in a more primitive form in SIMD extensions to modern micro processors).

Comment: @WayneConrad And yes, it's one of those 'easy' to understand terms everyone thinks about being very clearly defined - which it is not - and very specific - which it as well isn't. Like all of these generic terms, it's a great term when both sides know what particular topic it is intended, but  useless if not confusing outside such setting